# How do I create a pandas dataframe to show each topic (index/keywords) with all the keywords in each row. I'd like the keywords to be present

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How do I turn this:

```
for index,topic in enumerate(LDA.components_):
    #print(f'Top 10 words for Topic #(index)')
    print([cv.get_feature_names()[i] for i in topic.argsort()[-15:]])
    print('\n')
```

Which prints this: `[u'instance', u'breached', u'utilization', u'file', u'query', u'Threshold', u'Custom', u'Oracle', u'Device', u'Host', u'SRC', u'Name', u'prod', u'net', u'pncint']`

into my existing `df` dataframe?

I am able to get the topic models numbers to print BUT NOT the actually words themselves. I would like for the topic number to be in a separate column from the words printed out.

Desired output:

DF:
Column(1)                             column (2)
CN Topic:                        CN Topic results:
1,                               intranet, help
7,                               mac, mouse
5, (going down)               heres, by, computer

Comment: Are you using Python 2?

Comment: I am using python 3

Comment: Can you give an example of your desired output?